# C# PathTooLongException

Tags: c#

I'm working on an assignment for a C# class of mine. I need to make a program using visual studio 2012 that opens and reads in a text file and reports the number of spam words plus the probability the message is spam. I think I got the code down, but I'm getting an exception when opening the file:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.PathTooLongException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Additionally, the filename (what contains the file itself) contains the path name C:\Spam message.txt in addition to the text itself, which it shouldn't. I've basically hit a brick wall in trying to figure this out.

This is the main method in the first class

```
public void ScanMessage(string filename)
    {
        spamCount = 0;
        spamProbability = 0.0;

        StreamReader fileReader;
        FileStream input = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //This is where the exception is pointing to.
        fileReader = new StreamReader(input);
        messageRead = fileReader.ReadLine();

        while (messageRead != null)
        {
            messageRead = fileReader.ReadLine();
        }
        //Converts message to lowercase
        filename.ToLower();

        //For each word in spam phrases, look through the message. If a spam phrase is found,
        //increment spamCount and add it to the sorteddictionary, or adds an entry to the
        //sortedDictionary if it already exists
        foreach (var word in spamPhrases)
        {
            if (filename.IndexOf(word) != -1)
            {
                spamCount++;
                messageSpamPhrases.Add(word, 1);
            }

           /* else
            {
                ++messageSpamPhrases[word];
            }*/
        }

        spamProbability = spamCount / 30.0 * 100.0;

        //This is for the list of spam phrases found
        phrasesFound = new String[messageSpamPhrases.Count() + 1];
        phrasesFound[0] = string.Format("{0,-22}{1,-12}\n", "Phrase", "Count");
        int x = 1;

        foreach (String key in messageSpamPhrases.Keys)
        {
            phrasesFound[x++] = String.Format("{0,-25} {1,-25}", key, messageSpamPhrases[key]);
        }

        //The message of probability of spam
        spamResult = String.Format("This message has a {0}% chance of being a spam message", spamProbability);

        input.Close();
```

And the method for analyzing it via a button in the form

```
private void analyzeBtn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileChooser = new OpenFileDialog();

        fileChooser.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";

        fileChooser.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        fileChooser.FilterIndex = 2;
        fileChooser.RestoreDirectory = true;
        //fileChooser.Multiselect = false;

        DialogResult result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string filename = fileChooser.FileName;

            //result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
            StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filename);

            while (filename != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text += filename;
                filename = fileReader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        //textBox1.Text = filename;
        spam.ScanMessage(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Show();
        listBox1.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (var element in spam.PhrasesFound)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(element);
        }
        listBox1.EndUpdate();

        label2.Text = spam.spamResult;

        listBox1.Show();              
    }
```

The only help I really need is figuring why this error is happening. Any pointers?

Comment: Why it's happening? It's telling you. Your path is too long. You're probably not opening the file you think you're opening. Breakpoint and check that your logic is opening the correct file.

Comment: Yes the exception is pretty clear.

Comment: Did you verify that the full path, including the directory, is less than 260 characters?

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on the  `new FileStream(filename, ...` line and take a screenshot of the debugger with `filename` shown in the watch window.

Comment: Check your "filename". It could contain more than 260 characters.

Comment: Damn, to me there seems to be a heck of a lot going wrong here.
First of all you are concatenating the lines in your file to the textbox. Why? 1) Do you want to scan the file itself or does the file contain paths of files to be scanned? In the latter case you should at least add a separator between each read filename but then again a textbox is the worst option to pass a list of filenames. 2) in your `ScanMessage`, you consistently overwrite messageRead so that it will always contain the last line only. Then you check the `filename` against the spam list rather than the contents.

Answer (score 0):

> The exception that is thrown when a path or file name is longer than the system-defined maximum length.

-

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character.

-

> If your code does not have [PathDiscovery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionattribute.pathdiscovery(v=vs.110).aspx) permission, the error message for this exception may contain only file or directory names instead of full paths.

-

> Full paths must not exceed 260 characters to maintain compatibility with Windows operating systems. For more information about this restriction, see the entry [Long Paths in .NET](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=163666) in the BCL Team blog.

Answer (score 0):

The Culprit is here:

you are adding Text you are reading to the filename, ergo. the filename is going to be big (apart from that it may contain invalid characters)

```
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string filename = fileChooser.FileName;

                //result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();
                StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filename);

                while (filename != null)
                {
                    textBox1.Text += filename;
                    filename = fileReader.ReadLine(); // <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                }
            }
```

I think you wanted to do this:

```
   if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string filename = fileChooser.FileName;

                StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filename);

               string line;
               while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
               {
                    textBox1.Text += line+"\r\n";
               }
            }
```

Comment: Okay, that fixed that exception, but now another error popped up saying illegal characters in path.

Comment: @MichaelShonsey Do you want to scan the file itself or does the file contain paths of files to be scanned? If the first then why not just call `ScanMessage(...., fileChooser.FileName)`  - You are not being clear on what _exactly_ you wish to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to scan the file itself. Only scanning 1 .txt file containing a message.

Answer (score 0):

In this piece:

```
        while (filename != null)
        {
            textBox1.Text += filename;
            filename = fileReader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    //textBox1.Text = filename;
    spam.ScanMessage(textBox1.Text);
```

the value of `textBox1.Text` get filled with everything that is in your file, due to the `+=`. That can be hundreds/thousands characters.

Then, you do a `spam.ScanMessage(textBox1.Text)` (that could contain thousands characters).
In the ScanMessage method you try to open a file with that path at the 4th statement. This overflows.

Do yourself a favor: learn how to debug. That will really make you life more easy.

Comment: I also apologize if I'm sounding like an idiot. This is, sadly, my first time working with opening files and whatnot in coding. I"m just not sure if I keep screwing something up constantly.

Comment: @MichaelShonsey just keep on going, it is a bit difficult in the beginning, we've all been there. Your code is not bad, but it could certainly use some improvement, that is why you are getting some undefined behavior. Try to see it from the enjoyable site: creating stuff that miraculously does things on your computer! Good luck with your class and don't be withdrawn for asking questions because you are getting downvotes. The SO community can sometimes be somewhat high on the standards :). Soon enough you will be the one answering questions!

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on your latest comment, I've given this a shot:

```
DialogResult result = fileChooser.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string filename = fileChooser.FileName;
    spam.ScanMessage(filename);
    //...
}
```

And:

```
public void ScanMessage(string filename)
{
    spamCount = 0;
    spamProbability = 0.0;

    var messageRead="";
    using(var input = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        messageRead = input.ReadToEnd();
    }
    //Converts message to lowercase
    messageRead = messageRead.ToLower();

    //For each word in spam phrases, look through the message. If a spam phrase is found,
    //increment spamCount and add it to the sorteddictionary, or adds an entry to the
    //sortedDictionary if it already exists
    foreach (var word in spamPhrases)
    {
        if (messageRead.Contains(word))
        {
            spamCount++;
            messageSpamPhrases.Add(word, 1);
        }
    }

    spamProbability = spamCount / 30.0 * 100.0;

    //This is for the list of spam phrases found
    phrasesFound = new String[messageSpamPhrases.Count() + 1];
    phrasesFound[0] = string.Format("{0,-22}{1,-12}\n", "Phrase", "Count");
    int x = 1;

    foreach (String key in messageSpamPhrases.Keys)
    {
        phrasesFound[x++] = String.Format("{0,-25} {1,-25}", key, messageSpamPhrases[key]);
    }

    //The message of probability of spam
    spamResult = String.Format("This message has a {0}% chance of being a spam message", spamProbability);
}
```

This is probably still not fully kicking it because parts of your code are missing. It should get you going a bit further though.

Comment: That seemed to do it. Just had to make a few more additions (Mainly make a few labels visible).

Comment: Also, thanks for bearing with me. I apologize if the answer was obvious and I wasn't seeing it.